# How do I successfully transfer MIDI OUT signal to Windows 7 (32 bit) Desktop PC?

Tags: connector, driver, input, midi, encoding

[image: what should be there in between]

**Things I have:**

1. I have an old type **MIDI input device** (Piano Keyboard Panel) which has **a MIDI "OUT"  port** (female type jack) that has **5 holes**. (and no USB port). it has a 9V power input (AC to DC adapter)
2. I have a 32 BIT assembled Desktop computer (Intel Microprocessor, Intel Motherboard and an NVIDIA graphics card) running on Windows 7, that has several standard **USB sockets** (female type).
3. In my desktop, I have a plenty of **ROLL piano apps** and **MIDI Editor apps**, which are asking for a MIDI Input device. Some of them also take input from my TEXT keyboard, but it is stressful for me to use the TEXT keyboard or the mouse as an input device, especially for inserting chords, and hinder fluency.
4. I have a **standard USB** (Male type) **plug**, taken out from a Standard USB Mouse, that has with **4 wires** connected to it.

**What I am trying to do:**

> I want to use that MIDI piano keyboard **as a** MIDI Input device for my Windows 7 MIDI apps.

**What I have tried already:**

1. I have downloaded various simple schematics from the internet (not displayed here) that **claims** to **directly connect** the MIDI port with an AUX/ RCA/ USB cables. None of the combinations worked. Some of the combination caused horrible buzzing in the built in speaker of the piano keyboard, and bleeping or flashing or flicker of the tiny LCD display screen of the piano input.
2. The apps keep saying **"No MIDI input device found"**.
3. The apps show a dropdown list that I have 2 MIDI output / synth interfaces (**"Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth"** and **"Microsoft MIDI Mapper"**), but it shows **"BLANK"** in the field for **MIDI input Interface** (even after I installed a few drivers from CASIO, ROLLAND, YAMAHA and a few random drivers from web, and restarted the machine for several times).
4. I have tried searching the In the control panel, the **"Device manager"** and the **"Device and printers"** options. They does not show any option for MIDI devices.

**So please suggest me :**

1. **Proper circuit diagram** to connect MIDI to USB port.
2. **Parts list** (Veroboards, IC chips, capacitors, resistors, diodes etc) with part number to do this.
3. How would I make Windows 7 (32 bit) to recognize this incoming USB signal, and to  send it to the MIDI applications in an appropriate format?

Note:

1. I Won't be able to put an online order due to some situations. The MIDI TO USB converters are not available in the local radio parts market and musical instrument market. Also not available in computer applience market.
2. The price is too high. (A reliable MIDI to USB converter such as ROLLAND UM-ONE MK2 costing about INR 3000. WIDI Master MIDI to Bluetooth costs INR 10,263).
3. I won't be able to purchase a separate microcontroller. I want to only adjust the voltage of the MIDI signal and ***I want to make the entire conversion and recognition through a custom made driver pack (.EXE, .DLL etc) within my existing system hardware.***

Comment: Just purchase a midi-to-USB interface from a reputable dealer and, install drivers at the PC. It'll be cheaper in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

With those specs, you can't build anything that works..

MIDI is not audio, do not connect it to audio input. MIDI is data.

You need a MIDI to USB adapter, or build one from a microcontroller or MCU board that can present itself as USB device, and write firmware that makes it look like USB MIDI adapter.

But you may have damaged the MIDI output already with incorrect cables so it may not work any more.

Cheap USB MIDI adapters do exist, but they often are unreliable. If you pay much less than half the price of the proper known brand adapter you mentioned, they are likely garbage products that almost work but are not built up to MIDI standards.

Comment: I can tell you the exact connection i tried. Are you sure I have damaged my MIDI device?

Comment: I took MIDI shield line to USB GND, MIDI Data line to USB Data + line and MIDI + voltage line to USB +5V line of a battery operated laptop.

Comment: The other configuration I tried is to add the USB Data - line with shield line. Although one of the internet schematic suggested to short circuit between MIDI Data line and + line, I did not tried that suggestion

Comment: I can't know the MIDI output port implementation of your device, so of course I am not sure, but there is a possibility you have damaged devices. If you did that, both the MIDI output and laptop USB port may have been damaged. Do not connect USB to anywhere else than USB compatible device. Don't blindly believe what people say on the internet how to connect things, they may be trolls, just like mobile phones can't be charged in a microwave oven or they don't become waterproof with OS update.

Comment: Even there are posts within the MIDI associatio that instructs one to connect MIDI with TRS plugs :O These are ridiculous https://www.midi.org/midi-articles/updated-how-to-make-your-own-3-5mm-mini-stereo-trs-to-midi-5-pin-din-cables

Comment: @AlwaysConfused No they are not ridiculous. To save space you can have a TRS connector instead of the big DIN connector. It is still a MIDI port. You can use TRS plugs for anything you want, such as guitar audio, headphones, MIDI data, power supply, and it does not mean you can't expect things to work together even if they have matcing connectors - like would you connect headphones to 12V power supply just because they have matching connectors?

Comment: thans I was surprised because MIDI and Audio are 2 different encoding. Does a MIDI signal also work as a headphone signal?

Comment: No of course not. MIDI is digital serial data sent as 5mA current loop.

Comment: Okey i got it. It is a TRS jack, but NOT an Audio jack right?

Comment: I can hear the experts are reading my activities and laughing out loudly.

Comment: Not a TRS jack for audio. Just a TRS jack for MIDI.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused The connector is just a piece of metal. As a user you always expect the same type of connection to have the same type of connector but sometimes the rule isn't followed - especially in things like audio, where people have a lot of customized equipment and customized cables, they may reach for the nearest connector instead of the "right" one. I worked on a product where we had a debug port, that was UART port but with a USB connector, because we had a lot of USB connectors, the technicians could remember it was weird, and the customers never saw it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to back up Justme's answer, you cannot make a USB-to-MIDI adapter with these restrictions - it is not possible.

The reason is that your computer software - even the driver - doesn't have direct access to the wires of the USB port. The USB port is connected to a USB Host Controller, a chip that speaks the USB protocol ("USB language") and translates to the CPU. The Host Controller performs functions like detecting whether something is plugged in, and polling each device 8000 times a second, and then telling the driver if it detects something actually happened. And it's hard-wired to use the USB protocol for this. So whatever you plug into a USB port absolutely must speak the USB protocol, not the MIDI protocol.

---

However, I can think of one possible way to make a cheap adapter. MIDI uses a very common framing protocol known as "UART", which is also used by the PC serial port - which is now obsolete, but still used by many people and it is very easy to get a USB UART adapter for just a few dollars (few hundred rupees) - [example](https://www.ebay.de/itm/352982598553?hash=item522f670399:g:dAwAAOSw9b9jicdn) (but you should find one for yourself).

Wikipedia shows an example schematic. The left half shows the wiring inside the keyboard. The right half shows the wiring inside your adapter. As you can see, it's just a few components - and I think the diode isn't even needed, because it's just for safety (protects the opto-isolator from damage if the cable is somehow plugged in backwards).

[image: MIDI in/out schematic]

So where it says "to UART", just wire that to the receive/RX line on your UART; 5V to 5V; ground to ground; then plug the UART's USB plug into your computer. It will show up as a serial port. If you set the baud rate to 31250 baud, you should be able to receive MIDI data.

How to make your computer treat it as a MIDI port, and not a serial port, I'm not sure. Thanks to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/910155/can-i-use-an-uart-serial-port-as-a-midi-device-in-linux) I see there is this Linux  called [ttyMIDI](https://launchpad.net/ttymidi) but I haven't tried it. It should be much easier on Linux than Windows, just because Linux is a *lot* more customizable, but maybe someone has created a way to do it on Windows.

**The UART adapter must be able to do 31250 baud.** I think most of these adapters are fine with it, but it's not a usual baud rate for PC serial ports, so maybe some adapters (that are designed to work as PC serial ports) don't allow it. I'm not sure if Linux also has a problem with it - I found [this](http://joost.damad.be/2009/05/how-to-set-serial-port-at-midi-speed-in.html) regarding USB adapters on Linux.

---

It should also be possible to use a PC serial port adapter ([example](https://www.reichelt.de/de/de/usb-a-konverter-1x-rs232-9-pol-pl-2303hxd-0-45-m-manhattan-151801-p282842.html)) instead of a UART adapter, but it will be slightly more difficult because the voltage is different, the voltage is reversed, and because you have to attach one of those serial port plugs, assuming that you want to plug your circuit into the adapter, not cut it apart and solder directly to the wires. I think most of these adapters *do* allow non-standard baud rates, just like the UART adapters.

Comment: The USB serial ports are basically similar to what you call USB UART adapters; but they just have the RS-232 transceiver and DE-9 connector. Any will do if you start modifying the adapter. Serial MIDI drivers do exist.

Comment: @Justme yeah, but then you have to modify the adapter. I'm aware that a serial port is a UART plus a circuit to convert the voltage (much like a MIDI port is a UART plus a different circuit to convert the voltage!)